# I am installing React Native CLI but this error is continuously persisting

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

Its been 5 days since I am getting this error. I have tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling it again from scratch but this error isnt going anywhere.When ever I run "npm start" it gives me this

> ProjectName@0.0.1 start
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\M Khalil\Desktop\ReactNative\myapp\ProjectName
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\M Khalil\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-01T08_45_52_276Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\M Khalil\Desktop\ReactNative\myapp\ProjectName>

what should I do please I need serious help. I am getting late with my project

I tried googling and installing and reinstalling everything but it doesnt work